# Unable to search by name and primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

The following query doesn't search by id (primary key) at all - it keeps assigning 0 to id and search_str to name. It does so properly if we use equals operator instead of matches for "id". Is there an issue with the following scope.

```
scope :or_search, lambda {|name| where(arel_table[:name].matches("%{search_str}%").or(arel_table[:id].matches("%#{search_str}%")))
```

Comment: Why do you have

   arel_table[:id].matches("%#{search_str}%")

should you have:  arel_table[:id].matches("#{search_str}")

Comment: Could you give more infos about your model plz?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do but first

```
arel_table[:name].matches("%{search_str}%")
```

You're missing the `#`, I think this should be

```
arel_table[:name].matches("%#{search_str}%")
```

Second you're not using your `name` argument anywhere, just from looking at this, maybe you want to replace `search_str` with `name`?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have made a typo which i think is you missed one closing curly brace at the end of the scope defination

Coming to an answer i think you are doing something which is either match id or title?(really i can not believe this you should not do this)

Note the "search_str" is coming from nowhere because the parameter to the block is "name" and hence you can compare it with whatever attribute of the table you want to compare :)

And the answer i can think for your problem is

scope :or_search, lambda {|title| where(arel_table[:title].matches("%#{title}%").or(arel_table[:id].matches("#{title}")))}
pare

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're just trying to understand why it doesn't work, or if you're looking for a working solution.

Anyway the following isn't in arel, but would work if you add it to the model:

```
def self.or_search(str)
  where("name like :input OR id like :input", input: "%#{str}%")
end
```